# Image not uploading in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to upload image in node js.

**my users routs code is**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var app    =   express();
var upload      =   multer({ dest: './uploads/'});
var dateFormat = require( 'dateformat' );

app.use( multer({ dest: './uploads/',

    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename+Date.now();
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {

        console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
    }
}));
router.post( '/upload-picture', function( req, res, next ) {            

    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```

and **uploads** folder is just one step back to routs folder means along with routs folder.

i got **File is uploaded** message but image is not uploaded in folder.  where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `multer` *twice*?

Comment: i just following steps from https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/